# How to set up an animation thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, animation, nsthread, runloop

I have a function `drawView` which is thread safe and does drawing for short periods of game animation. I have functions `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating`. I want a background thread to call `drawView` at a regular rate but only during the period that the animation is enabled.

In `startAnimating` I was going to call the view's `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` to get the thread running.

I'm a little confused about how to do the thread communication and initialize the drawing thread: specifically, setting up a runloop to receive display link messages and then at the end notifying the thread that it should exit and exiting the run loop cleanly when `stopAnimating` is called from the main thread. I want to ensure that `drawView` is never called after `stopAnimating`, and also that the drawing thread is not cancelled abruptly in the middle of the drawing operation. I have seen a lot of very poor answers to this kind of question on line.

Answer (score 0):

OK after reading the Apple pages all evening, I finally solved it with this code:

```
// object members
NSThread *m_animationthread;
BOOL m_animationthreadrunning;

- (void)startAnimating
{
    //called from UI thread
    DEBUG_LOG(@"creating animation thread");
    m_animationthread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animationThread:) object:nil];
    [m_animationthread start];
}

- (void)stopAnimating
{
    // called from UI thread
    DEBUG_LOG(@"quitting animationthread");
    [self performSelector:@selector(quitAnimationThread) onThread:m_animationthread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    // wait until thread actually exits
    while(![m_animationthread isFinished])
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
    DEBUG_LOG(@"thread exited");

    [m_animationthread release];
    m_animationthread = nil;
}

- (void)animationThread:(id)object
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        DEBUG_LOG(@"animation thread started");
        m_animationthreadrunning = YES;

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

        CADisplayLink *displaylink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkAction:)];
        [displaylink setFrameInterval:3];

        [displaylink addToRunLoop:runLoop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        while(m_animationthreadrunning)
        {
            [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
            DEBUG_LOG(@"runloop gap");
        }

        [displaylink removeFromRunLoop:runLoop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        DEBUG_LOG(@"animation thread quit");
    }
}

- (void)quitAnimationThread
{
    DEBUG_LOG(@"quitanimationthread called");
    m_animationthreadrunning = NO;
}

- (void)displayLinkAction:(CADisplayLink *)sender
{
    DEBUG_LOG(@"display link called");
    //[self drawView];
}
```

The reason I use the line `[self performSelector:@selector(quitAnimationThread) onThread:m_animationthread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]` and not simply set `m_animationthreadrunning = NO` in `stopAnimating` is because the run loop may not return in a timely fashion, but calling a selector forces it to return.